# How to install electrical cables in order

Tags: electrical

My ceiling light cables was loosen. I tried to remove them, sharpen them for better electrical contact, but i forgot to reinstall them in order. 
Please help me. Why i can't upload image over this thread?
Thank you.[image: there are 4 electrical cable delivering lights for living room, study room and hallway light(itself)]

Comment: Your question is very confusing.  Could you please edit it and be more clear about how it was, how it is now, what you're trying to do?  Also a couple of photos would probably be very helpful.

Comment: Please see this link on how to upload photos:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post

Comment: We are unable to follow your question well enough to be able to provide an answer. Try revising it to make it easy to get what you are saying

Comment: The wires aren't color coded.  All the information you need is (or rather, was) contained *in the positioning that they were hooked up previously*.  It sounds like you destroyed that information.

Comment: The above is picture from my ceiling. There are 4 wire cables : 1. Red (hot) and black, 2. Red and Black. 3. Red and White. 4. Red (single red). When i removed it from fittings i forgot the way back. This bundles deliver light system in living room, studying room and kitchen. Please kindly help me how to reinstall it back. Many thanks.

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: I'm living in Sydney Australia

Comment: I still remember when i remove wires from fittings, the single red was alone, two black twisted together. The rest can't recall it yet